# PostgreSQL - One-To-One - which approach is "better"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, one-to-one

I want to create a One-To-One relationship between two tables : `teachers` and `office` (the teacher is the owner of the relationship).
Looking up online, I found two different approaches :

First one, to define a `foreign key` in the office table and add constraints `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE`. Basically, a mandatory One-To-Many relationship with the UNIQUE constraint:
Like so :

```
CREATE TABLE office(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    floor SMALLINT CHECK (floor > 0 AND floor <= 10),
    size SMALLINT CHECK (size > 0),
    teacher_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES teachers(teacher_id)
);
```

And the second one where we **combine** the `primary key` **and** the `foreign key` in the office table into one row. Like so :

```
CREATE TABLE office(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES teachers(teacher_id),
    floor SMALLINT CHECK (floor > 0 AND floor <= 10),
    size SMALLINT CHECK (size > 0)
);
```

Functionally, it looks to me like both approaches work the same. The first one seems to use a little bit of extra memory, since it has one more row.

My question is:  What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?
Is one approach "better" than the other ?

Comment: Don't forget to add a foreign key from `teachers` to `office` as well, to enforce the one-to-one relationship. As it is now it's: 1-to-0/1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would go with the second approach, to share the exact same value for the primary key. For the `office` table the primary key should not be autogenerated (`serial`) but just an `int`.

For example you can do:

```
create table teachers (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(20) not null
);

create table office (
  id int primary key references teachers (id),
  floor smallint check (floor > 0 and floor <= 10),
  size smallint check (size > 0)
);

alter table teachers
add constraint fk_uq1_teachers_office
foreign key (id) references office (id) deferrable initially deferred;
```

Then inserting data could look like:

```
begin transaction;

insert into teachers (id, name) values (100, 'Mary');

insert into office (id, floor, size) values (100, 3, 850);

commit;
```

Notice that in order to enforce the 1-1 relationship **you need** to have two foreign keys: one from `teachers` to `office`, and one from `office` to `teachers`. Otherwise an application could insert data into `teachers` and forget to insert into `office`. Fortunately you are using PostgreSQL that implements the *standard* SQL feature of constraint deferrability as shown above.

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xqBc5SE85GMFkg9z7Hk1bt/0).

Comment: I understand. But I must ask you : why did you go with the second approach over the first one ?

Comment: @ROBlackSnail Simplicity: it's simple to have one identifier value instead of two. There's no need for two different values where one would do.

Comment: What if we want to create a new office for a teacher and delete the old one?

Comment: @Andrew I would tend to model an office change as a 1:N relationship. It's probably not advisable to delete the old row, but I get the point.

Answer (score 5):

If this is really a 1-1 relationship, why not just include the columns describing the office in the `teachers` table?

There is probably a reason why you don't want to do that.  One important reason is that `office`s can exist without `teacher`s.  For instance, if your school has no summer session, then the offices continue to exist.

That suggests that offices are independent of teachers.  So, you want a separate table with a separate primary key for them.

In your second model -- where the primary key *is* the foreign key to `teachers` -- you are essentially saying that an office is a type of teacher, not a separate entity.

Two notes, though:

First, Postgres not recommends `generated always as identity` rather than `serial`.  And the second table should not be using a `serial` column for the primary key; it should be `int`:

```
CREATE TABLE office (
    id int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES teachers(teacher_id),
    floor SMALLINT CHECK (floor > 0 AND floor <= 10),
    size SMALLINT CHECK (size > 0)
);
```

It doesn't make sense to have an automatically assigned column be a foreign key reference.

Comment: I am actually learning PostgreSQL right now, so the `teacher` and `office` tables were just examples I made up to test these 2 approaches. You are right, in a real world scenario, an office should be able to be vancant.

Answer (score 2):

Bi-directional mandatory foreign keys a can become a maintenance nightmare. Another option would to model the teacher to office as a m:m and then put partial unique indexes to constrain them. That gives you great flexibility as both teachers and offices are both independent entities and if ever needed you have the teacher and office relationship history. As it stands now an office can not exist unless a teacher is assigned. (You could make office.teacher null-able. And at a minimum should.). Adopting the m:m structure your table definitions become:

```
create table teachers (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(20) not null
);
 
create table offices (
  id int primary key, 
  floor smallint check (floor > 0 and floor <= 10),
  size smallint check (size > 0)
);

 
create table teacher_offices
      (id             integer generated always as identity
      ,teacher_id     integer not null
      ,office_id      integer not null
      ,effective_date date    not null default now()::date
      ,end_date       date  
      ,constraint teacher_office_pk 
                  primary key(id)
      ,constraint to2office_fk  
                  foreign key (office_id)
                  references offices (id) 
                  on delete cascade
      ,constraint to2teacher_fk  
                  foreign key (teacher_id)
                  references teachers (id)
                  on delete cascade
      );
     
-- create the partial unique index     
create unique index office_already_occupied_by_teacher
          on teacher_offices (office_id)
          where end_date is null;
         
create unique index teacher_already_has_office
          on teacher_offices (teacher_id)
          where end_date is null;
```

See here for [full example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=63572c80f417e2be331f8d60831b2543).

Comment: What if you wanted to enforce that teachers must have an office?

Comment: You don't want to enforce bi-directional foreign key.